# Reflection: Search object for string value, recursively, and then reporting paths

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion

I am trying to look for a value in a complex object. Does anyone know if there is a helper class out there that does this already?

Would like to be able to search an object, while observing endless loop protection to find a tostring value that contains "foo" and then to return the property path that foo was found in. Or an array of paths foo was found in.

So if someone has handy existing code before I undertake this myself; I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is you want to keep a `Stack` of the current property while you recursively search for the value you're after and also a `HashSet` of visited objects and skip them.  You also want to be careful with your exception handling so an exception in the middle doesn't mess up the stack.

```
    public static string[] FindPathToProperty(object item, string propertyValueToFind)
    {
        var pathToProperty = new Stack<string>();
        var visitedObjects = new HashSet<object> {item};

        FindPathToProperty(item, propertyValueToFind, pathToProperty, visitedObjects);

        var finalPath = pathToProperty.ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(finalPath);
        return finalPath;
    }

    private static bool FindPathToProperty(object item, string propertyValueToFind, Stack<string> pathToProperty, HashSet<object> visitedObjects)
    {
        foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            try
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(item, null);

                if (visitedObjects.Contains(value))
                {
                    continue;                       
                }

                visitedObjects.Add(value);

                pathToProperty.Push(property.Name);

                bool found = false;
                try
                {
                    found = propertyValueToFind.Equals(value) ||
                            FindPathToProperty(value, propertyValueToFind, pathToProperty, visitedObjects);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!found)
                    {
                        pathToProperty.Pop();
                    }
                }
                if (found)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Test(new { X = "find" }, "X");
        Test(new { X = "no", Y = "find" }, "Y");
        Test(new { A = new { X = "no", Y = "find" } }, "A.Y");
    }

    private static void Test(object item, string expected)
    {
        string actual = string.Join(".", FindPathToProperty(item, "find"));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}\r\n      {2}",
                          actual == expected ? "ok " : "BAD",
                          expected,
                          actual);
    }
```

Comment: This is genius! thank you so much. Wish the up arrow was a button, allowed multiple "ups" and i could hold down the enter key with sticky tape.

Comment: @Valamas, np, we use reflection a lot and this is almost the same as a function we have in our internal common library.  LINQ also works really well with reflection, but wouldn't help here much 'cause there's no recursive LINQ (at least not yet).

Comment: Your code won't work if there is an IList object embedded as child properties.